# Facebook interests list not getting iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using `SLRequest` to get basic profile info. For getting interests i am using `user_interests` permission and the following code,

```
NSURL *meurl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/interests"]];

SLRequest *merequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                          requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                    URL:meurl
                                             parameters:nil];

merequest.account = _facebookAccount;

[merequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {


    NSError * error1=nil;
    NSDictionary *responseJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error1];

}];
```

But the above code gives the empty response like as follows,

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Can anyone give the solution for this problem. Thanks.

Comment: It's possible that the respective user has added nothing to his interests, and that's the reason you get nothing in return. I'd recommend to thest this with user_likes and requesting the /me/likes edge...

Comment: @Tobi, i tested user_likes. Its getting the response correctly.. More over i already added interests into my facebook profile.. But still not working....i also tested using another fb account but no result.

Answer (score 0):

There could be only 2 possible reasons for this-

1. There are no interests of the user queried (as @Tobi has mentioned), or
2. Your access token used by your api call do not have the permissions `user_interests`. This could be because you've added this permission later and since the session was active it didnt asked for the new permission.

   You can check what permissions you've granted to the app from [here](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications)

   If this is the problem, you can either logout from the facebook in your app and login again or delete the app from [here](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications) so that it will ask for the authorization again.

Hope that helps. Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the response. Pls check my comment above.

Comment: If you are sure that you are using the correct token, you can report a bug, here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/